# Javascript canvas images are coming out blocky when stacking on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I'm randomly generating two types of clouds, and the clouds are intended to stack on top of each other a bit and move slowly (like clouds irl would). 
So essentially I'm drawing a cloud image, clearing the area, moving the image over (by recreating it in a different position), and creating another cloud and repeating the process, but when the clouds are stacking on top of each other I'm getting a square area in between the stacked clouds. Not sure how to fix it.

### Check this out: (see how the clouds have a block-like look as they stack over eachother)

http://testcloudsmc.bitballoon.com

### Here's the full code:

https://repl.it/FTo8/3

And here's the most relevant parts of the code:

```
------------------------------------------------
var canvas; var ctx; var frameRate; var assets = [];
window.onload = function(){
canvas    = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
ctx                 = canvas.getContext('2d');
frameRate           = 1000/30; //30 fps

//Decides on a x position for clouds:
for(var f = 0;f<Math.floor(Math.random()*40)+10;f++){
    cloudsarrayxpos[f] = Math.floor(Math.random()*800)+10;

}
/* Move/Render images */
for (var a = 0; a < 21; a++){
        assets[a] = document.getElementById(a);
        console.log(assets[a]);
};

/* CREATE OBJECTS FUNCTIONS: */
var clouds = function(x,y,h,w){
    ctx.clearRect(x,y,w,h);
    if((x>300)||(x<100)){
     ctx.drawImage(assets[7],x,y,w,h);
    }else{
     ctx.drawImage(assets[20],x,y,w,h);
    }
} //end of clouds function

function animate(){
    for(var g = 0; g<cloudsarrayxpos.length;g++){
        clouds(cloudsarrayxpos[g],(5*g),300,200);
        cloudsarrayxpos[g]+=(Math.random()*.1)+.05; //changing the x position of each cloud in the array making it appear to be moving
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

}//end of window.onload
```

Comment: You need to create the cloud images with alpha channel. Png images support alpha channel. Where there is no cloud alpha should be 0, where full opaque alpha is 255 and everything inbetween. You can also load the image, create an offscreen canvas, draw the cloud on that canvas. Get the image data then use the mean inverse sum of each colour channel to set the alpha. Eg `imgData.data[3] = 255 - (imgData.data[0] + imgData.data[1] + imgData.data[2])/3;` do for each pixel. Then put the data back onto the offscreen canvas and draw the canvas  eg `ctx.drawImage(offScreenCanvas,0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are clearing the canvas in each cloud spot before drawing it.
That means that the transparency (alpha) values of the cloud images don't come into play as each resulting pixel is composed only of the last image that was drawn on it.

To fix this, only clear the canvas once per animation cycle.

Specifically:

1. Remove `ctx.clearRect` from `clouds` function
2. Add this at the top of the `animate` function:
   `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1300, 600);`